# How do you return identical elements based on a single attribute from a list of objects with multiple attributes?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of objects with several attributes (`strLabel`, `intX`, `intY`) in python. I have to get the leftmost, rightmost, topmost, and bottommost values from the list, which can be a single point or multiple points. I was thinking of having a separate function that sorts the list based on `intX` and `intY`, then returning the most positive and most negative objects. How do I return those objects if there are more than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create functions to determine the property you want to get the `max` or `min` of and use it as a key:

To determine how `right` a point is we can look at its' `x` value:

```
def rightness(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return x
```

Similarly how `top` it is:

```
def topness(xy):
    x, y = xy
    return y
```

A set of points to test:

```
points = {
   (1,3),
   (0, 0),
   (5,3),
   (1,-2),
}
```

And simply using python's built-ins:

```
rightmost = max(points, key=rightness)
leftmost = min(points, key=rightness)

topmost = max(points, key=topness)
bottommost = min(points, key=topness)
```

The result:

```
print('leftmost: %s,rightmost: %s, topmost: %s, bottommost:%s' % (
    leftmost, rightmost, topmost, bottommost))
```

To return more than one you could find the value you're looking for, and extract similar values from the set of points, suppose `bottommost` point is at `(1, -2)` you could do:

```
bottommosts = [p for p in points if p[1] == -2]
```

Comment: Will these work for points that have labels, (A01, 1, -2) and such? I mean, the objects that I defined have labels as an attribute. Also, if I understand it correctly, 

`bottommosts = [p for p in points if p[1] == -2]`

will, for example, return `(1, -2)` and `(3, -2)`. Did I get that right?